# how to get the resourcekey from google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the resourcekey of file from google drive api

In the description of google api
On 13th September they gonna update for file permission
they said
'you must update your code for accessing files to include the appropriate resource keys'
'The resource key of an item is returned on the resourceKey field of the file metadata in the Drive API response'

but when I trying to get the file I can not find the resourcekey from the fields of the file metadata
and also When i trying to do on the google api test, the response also doesn't have the resource key
this follow is the result of api test

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv",
 "etag": "\"MTYyODc0MTU1ODg4Nw\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv",
 "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv/edit?usp=drivesdk",
 "embedLink": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv",
 "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
 "thumbnailLink": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv&v=3&s=AMedNnoAAAAAYRtUMTI6h451YaMRq96KNGUB_WwYBPDv&sz=s220",
 "title": "CSS_v1_212232173224",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
 "labels": {
  "starred": false,
  "hidden": false,
  "trashed": false,
  "restricted": false,
  "viewed": true
 },
 "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
 "createdDate": "2021-08-12T04:10:07.115Z",
 "modifiedDate": "2021-08-12T04:12:38.887Z",
 "lastViewedByMeDate": "2021-08-17T04:16:16.628Z",
 "markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
 "sharedWithMeDate": "2021-08-17T04:16:16.628Z",
 "version": "10",
 "parents": [],
 "exportLinks": {
  "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv",
  "text/tab-separated-values": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv&exportFormat=tsv",
  "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv&exportFormat=pdf",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv4&exportFormat=xlsx",
  "text/csv": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv&exportFormat=csv",
  "application/zip": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv&exportFormat=zip",
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv&exportFormat=ods"
 },
 "userPermission": {
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"kKO0QvvB0TR5MI4KTDoDeWQE7AU\"",
  "id": "me",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1iLXfgFeTJi5Fhv/permissions/me",
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user"
 },
 "fileSize": "13706",
 "quotaBytesUsed": "13706",
 "ownerNames": [
  ""
 ],
 "owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "",
   "isAuthenticatedUser": false,
   "permissionId": "",
   "emailAddress": ""
  }
 ],
 "lastModifyingUserName": "",
 "lastModifyingUser": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "",
  "isAuthenticatedUser": false,
  "permissionId": "",
  "emailAddress": ""
 },
 "capabilities": {
  "canCopy": true,
  "canEdit": false
 },
 "editable": false,
 "copyable": true,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "shared": true,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "appDataContents": false,
 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ]
}
```

how can i get the resourcekey for the file??

Comment: I cant get it to work either I have pinged someone at google i will get back to you when i hear something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the resourceKey security update is already activated in your domain by going to Google Admin. You can find more detailed answer here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196862507

Comment: hello i check up security update on Google Admin. But that is already updated like your answer. and then i try again the api on your api site but stil i can't get the resourcekey  ( https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
 Is it correct that the resourceKey updated??? 
And is the correct that the files's get method gives the resourceKey?

Comment: The link to the issue tracker is dead do you have a more updated link?

Comment: oh i couldn't see the issuetracker.. could you give me the like again??

Answer (score 1):

### New Update

Phase 3: Drive enforces update—Beginning September 13, 2021
The update should finish by the end of September 2021.

#### To apply the security update:

1. Sign in to your Google Admin console.
2. From the Admin console Home page, go to Appsand thenGoogle Workspaceand thenDrive and Docs.
3. Click Sharing settingsand thenSecurity update for files.
4. Choose how to apply the update:
5. Apply the security update to all impacted files
6. Remove security update from all impacted files (not recommended)
   (Optional if applying the update) To let users remove or apply the update to files that they own or manage, check the allow box.
   If you made any changes, click Save.

> Wait for the change affect ( maybe up to 24 hours )

#### How to verify the setup

Open google drive ( Search Box )

- is:security_update_applied
- is:security_update_applied type:folder

[image: is:security_update_applied]

**Result :**

[image]

#### API to get the file

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${file_id}?fields=*

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

- shortcutDetails.targetResourceKey string  The ResourceKey for the target file.    
- resourceKey   string  A key needed to access the item via a shared link.
```

So a link that used to look like [https://drive.google.com/file/d/${file_id}/](https://drive.google.com/file/d/$%7Bfile_id%7D/)

will now look like
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/${file_id}/view?resourcekey=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/$%7Bfile_id%7D/view?resourcekey=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx)